Better way to access nested Array item and get values of one specific key only
I am learning Vanilla JavaScript. I have a JSON object like below:
{
  "createdBy" : "System",
  "createdDate" : "2002-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
  "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
  "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
  "id" : 2,
  "softwarename" : "AcrobatReater",
  "softwareprovider" : "ADOBE",
  "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@adobe.com",
  "customers" : [ {
    "name" : "CUSTOMER1",
    "_links" : {
      "softwares" : [ {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/1"
      }, {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
      } ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "CUSTOMER2",
    "_links" : {
      "softwares" : [ {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/1"
      }, {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
      } ]
    }
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
    },
    "appSoftware" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
    }
  }
}

To get the names of customers I am doing it like this:
      function custFunction(data.customers) {
            let htmlToSend = ''

            for (let i = 0; i < data.customers.length; i++) {
                const [key, val] = Object.entries(data.customers[i]);
                htmlToSend += `${key.toString().split(',')[1]}</br>`;
            }
            return htmlToSend;
        }

This is getting the job done but it seems like a dirty solution. I am worried what if the more fields are introduced at the entity level, it may break. Is there a better way to get just the name's values (CUSTOMER1 and CUSTOMER2 in this case). Is there any functional style of coding to achieve it where we can just target the names and their values only?

I think you are doing too much in your custom code, this functionality is already covered by Javascript built-in modules. And, as you imagined, in a functional style.
data.customers.map(c => c.name).join("</br>")

That is it. It would return "CUSTOMER1</br>CUSTOMER2". If you actually want the output to be "CUSTOMER1</br>CUSTOMER2</br>", you could do this, instead:
data.customers.map(c => c.name + "</br>").join("")

Doing anything more than that is just overdoing it.

I think it's as simple as building an array and pushing the name property into it:


 function custFunction() {
   let htmlToSend = ''
const names = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < data.customers.length; i++) {
     names.push(data.customers[i].name)
   }
   return names;
 }

 const data = {
   "createdBy": "System",
   "createdDate": "2002-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
   "lastModifiedBy": "System",
   "lastModifiedDate": "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
   "id": 2,
   "softwarename": "AcrobatReater",
   "softwareprovider": "ADOBE",
   "softwareprovidercontactemail": "admin@adobe.com",
   "customers": [{
     "name": "CUSTOMER1",
     "_links": {
       "softwares": [{
         "href": "http://localhost:8080/softwares/1"
       }, {
         "href": "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
       }]
     }
   }, {
     "name": "CUSTOMER2",
     "_links": {
       "softwares": [{
         "href": "http://localhost:8080/softwares/1"
       }, {
         "href": "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
       }]
     }
   }],
   "_links": {
     "self": {
       "href": "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
     },
     "appSoftware": {
       "href": "http://localhost:8080/softwares/2"
     }
   }
 }

console.log(custFunction())



But also, you seem to be using data.customer as the parameter to your function, which doesn't seem quite right. Either pass data.customers into your function, or just use the Object (it's not JSON; JSON is a string) itself as a global variable (as I have in my example).

Yea, definitely I agree it makes sense to look at a more explicit way of extracting the data you need.
Also I think there are a few things in your example that look like they may not work but can address that as we go through the answer.
Initially I think, if you're looking for an approach that somewhat follows the functional approach, it makes sense to split the process of collecting the required data and compiling it into html.
So we can create a function that is designed to take the some input in the shape of the customers field of your data and return an array of strings representing the names of each customer. I'll put the example in typescript but you if you want to use javascript you can just ignore the types.
The function may look like this
const getCustomerNames = (
  customerData: (typeof data)["customers"],
): readonly string[] => customerData.map((data) => data.name);

This is in my opinion the functional way of expressing it, where the function itself is a variable. You could also express it as a function

function getCustomerNames (
  customerData: (typeof data)["customers"],
): readonly string[]{
    return customerData.map((data) => data.name);
} 

Here what we are doing is just mapping over each array entry of the customers data field and taking the name only.
If you were to create a method that expects the actual data object as input you would just call it like getCustomerData(data.customers)
So to be very formal with the flow of data, but generally you could just call getCustomerNames with data.customers, you could have
const getCustomerNameFromData(data:typeof data){
    return getCustomerNames(data.customers)
}

const getCustomerNames(customerData: (typeof data)["customers"])=>...

And then for getting the html string from the names, you can create a function that takes as input a string array and returns a string which represents the html, for example
const getNamesHTML = (names:readonly string[])=>names.join("</br>")

This simply takes the names and joins them with a line break. Join just takes an array and joins the elements with a specified separator.
Here is a playground link with examples that may be help.

I'll just add here for your code some things that look off, data.customers as an argument should be invalid syntax, so I don't think it should work normally, and also key.toString().split(',')[1] using 1 as index should be giving you the _links object of each item in the customers array as js is 0 indexed so arrays start at index 0.
